# Why is my ListView Model not updated/changed?

Tags: c#, listview, maui

my goal for that part of the program is, to update a ListView with Textboxes with a dictionary filled with Data from a MySQL Server.
Theoretically everything works fine up until the point, where it would actually update the ListView in RunTime which does not seem to work.

```
    public void EditInitiativeData()
    {
        SQLStuff PullData= new SQLStuff();
        playerDict = PullData.GetInitiativeLoop();

        DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = playerDict;

        foreach (var player in playerDict)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.Key + " " + player.Value);
        }

    }
```

*This part of the program gets the Data, transfers it into a dictionary, which then "should" update my ListView*

`public Dictionary<string, int> playerDict = new SQLStuff().GetInitiativeLoop();`

*This is a reference of what I did before trying to automate the process. This here works fine, but does not work in the current State of the Project.*

If there is anything else needed, I would be happy to provide it for you.
Thanks in advance.

There was not really much to try, as I do not really understand why it does not work. Possible reasons may be, that a direct change on runtime is not possible.
I checked if the dictionary actually contains data, which it does. So I believe that the mistake or problem should be in this line:

`DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = playerDict;`

Update 1:

As mentioned I should have placed more Info and Code to work with.

At first I would like to clarify my problem more deeply:

Every 2s a pull Request for Data is send to my SQL Server to retrieve the newest Data from a table. That works completely fine. Everything is also put correctly into the necessary library. The Problem is that the Textboxes within the ListView do not refresh/change within the UI, while being opened. Before I implemented automatic Updates with SQL I reopened the Window manually and it worked, though I believe that is because of reloading the entire page.

I tried to add @Jessie Zhang -MSFTs code that was put into an answer. While I implemented the code, the problem remains the same. (Probably because of my own missing experience though I will give you the updated code nontheless.

```
    public void EditInitiativeData()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        SQLStuff PullData= new SQLStuff();
        playerDict = PullData.GetInitiativeLoop();

       // DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = playerDict;

        foreach (var player in playerDict)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.Key + " " + player.Value);

            Item item = new Item { Key = player.Key, Value = player.Value };
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = Items;

     
    }
```

*The interface INotifyPropertyChanged was implemented exactly as written by the author.*

```
        public Dictionary<string, int> GetInitiativeLoop()
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> InitiativeDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            string connStr = MySettings.Default.DBConnection2;
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT identifikation, playername, reihenfolge FROM initiativeorder ORDER BY reihenfolge DESC, dexbonus DESC;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    InitiativeDic.Add(rdr[1].ToString(), (int)rdr[2]);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
           /* foreach (var player in InitiativeDic)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.Key + " " + player.Value);
            }*/

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done.");
            //var sortedDict = test.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            return (Dictionary<string, int>)InitiativeDic;
        }
```

*As requested this is the Method connecting and creating the Data that I try to use within the ListView TextCells*

```
        <ListView
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.RowSpan="9"
                Grid.Column="14"
                x:Name ="DMInitiativeList"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Margin="5"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                MaximumWidthRequest="50"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                SeparatorColor="Grey"
                Scale="1.5">
            
          
                    
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell           
                                        
                                        Text="{Binding Key}"
                                        Detail="{Binding Value}"
                                        DetailColor="White"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        Height="20"
                                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Update 2:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Initiative_Order;

public partial class dmscreen : ContentPage
{

   // public Dictionary<string, int> playerDict = new SQLStuff().GetInitiativeLoop();

    public class SQLKontakt : SQLStuff { }
    public class TimerKontakt : TimerShit { }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, int> playerDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    // public static Dictionary<string, int> playerDict;


    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public string Key { get; set; }

       // public int Value { get; set; }
        private int _value;
        public int Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _value, value);
            }
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }


    public dmscreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        StartTimer();

        

    }

    public void EditInitiativeData()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

              SQLStuff PullData= new SQLStuff();
              playerDict = PullData.GetInitiativeLoop();



        // DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = playerDict;

        foreach (var player in playerDict)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.Key + " " + player.Value);

            Item item = new Item { Key = player.Key, Value = player.Value };
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = Items;

     
    }







    public static void StartTimer()
    {
        TimerShit.Timer();
        
    }



    public void sendInitiativeData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLKontakt Kontakt = new SQLKontakt();
        Kontakt.SendInitiativeDataSQL(EntryName.Text, EntryInitiative.Text, EntryDex.Text);


        int basicRoll = Int32.Parse(EntryInitiative.Text);
        int dexbonus = Int32.Parse(EntryDex.Text);

        int finaleReihenfolge = basicRoll + (dexbonus);

        EntryName.Text = "";
        EntryInitiative.Text = "";
        EntryDex.Text = "";
    }


    public void rollD20(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random roll = new Random();
        int d20Roll = roll.Next(1, 21);
        string fastRoll = d20Roll.ToString();
        RollWertLabel.Text = fastRoll;
    }

    private void GoBackMainscreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(MySettings.Default.SaveShit);
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    }


   
}
```

*This is the whole code regarding this page.*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, your question doesn't seem to include all relevant parts of the code. Please show the model class and the XAML where you're binding to the data. Does your Model/ViewModel implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface? Are you using the MVVM pattern?

Comment: what is the type of `playerDict`? did you check if it has any data? and correct data?

Comment: You have not described the actual problem.  “Does not work” is not a helpful description of the problem

Comment: Learn about data binding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/?view=net-maui-7.0. When you finish with the theory, learn to use this for practice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/

Comment: What's the code of `Item` in your code? And when is this  method `public void EditInitiativeData()`called?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT

public void EditInitiativeData() is being called every 2s through System.Timers.Timer.

I used the code that you wrote the exact same way and implemented it without changing anything. The way I understood it, there was no need to change it.

Comment: Could you please post the code of YourPage.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 0):

> public Dictionary<string, int> playerDict = new
> SQLStuff().GetInitiativeLoop();

From the code you posted ,I found that the type of `playerDict` is `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Generally, we usually define a Model for the binded item for the ListView.

For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

I created a demo and achieved this function, you can refer to the following code:

1.create a model `Item.cs` and  add two properties `Key`  and `Value`,and we need to  implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this class. Suppose you want the UI refresh automatically while changing the value of property `Value`,you can add code like this:

```
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _value, value);
        }
    }
```

the whole code is:

```
 public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 

    public string Key { get; set; }

    //public int Value { get; set; }
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _value, value);
        }
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

2. `NewPage.xaml.cs`

Here, I converted `Dictionary<string, int> playerDict`  to `ObservableCollection<Item> Items` and set ItemsSource for listview `DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = Items;`

```
   public partial class NewPage : ContentPage 
   {
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, int> playerDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     public NewPage()
          {
            InitializeComponent();
            initData();
           }

    private void initData()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        playerDict.Add("1", 100);
        playerDict.Add("2", 200);
        playerDict.Add("3", 300);

        foreach (var player in playerDict)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.Key + " " + player.Value);

            Item item = new Item {Key=player.Key,Value= player.Value };
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        DMInitiativeList.ItemsSource = Items;

    }
```

3. `NewPage.xaml`

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   ```

   ```
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button  Text="reset item data" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="10"></Button>

        <ListView x:Name="DMInitiativeList"    HasUnevenRows="True"    >
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                      <HorizontalStackLayout HeightRequest="38">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Caption" ></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Value}"  VerticalOptions="Center"  Margin="20,0,0,0"></Label>
                      </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
   ```